# How to use quarkus.kubernetes-config.secrets.enabled in application.yml?

Tags: kubernetes, client, runtime, quarkus, kubernetes-secrets

I'm struggling at having secrets read using application.yml.

When I do:

```
quarkus:
    application:
        name: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service
    kubernetes-config:
        enabled: true
        fail-on-missing-config: false
        config-maps: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-configmap
        secrets: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-secrets
            enabled: true
```

The build fails with:

```
Failed to build quarkus application: mapping values are not allowed here
    in 'reader', line 16, column 20:
                enabled: true
                        ^
```

When:

```
quarkus:
    application:
        name: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service
    kubernetes-config:
        enabled: true
        secrets.enabled: true
        fail-on-missing-config: false
        config-maps: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-configmap
        secrets: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-secrets
```

The build fails with:

```
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.kubernetes-config."secrets.enabled"" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or you did not make a typo
```

When:

```
quarkus.kubernetes-config.secrets.enabled: true
quarkus:
    application:
        name: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service
    kubernetes-config:
        enabled: true
        fail-on-missing-config: false
        config-maps: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-configmap
        secrets: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-secrets
```

The build succeed but the service fails at startup with:

Configuration is read from Secrets [pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-secrets], but **quarkus.kubernetes-config.secrets.enabled is false**. Check if your application's service account has enough permissions to read secrets.

When I look at this commit: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/93f00af9444deafe950afa1fad60f56fceb81ca3

Line 48: // TODO: should probably use converter here

Could it be because the property is not converted from yaml?

Comment: Hi, does everything work fine if you use `application.properties` instead of `application.yaml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is just about how to write the correct YAML. It should be:

```
quarkus:
    application:
        name: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service
    kubernetes-config:
        enabled: true
        fail-on-missing-config: false
        config-maps: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-configmap
        secrets:
            ~: pi-quarkus-fund-persistence-service-secrets
            enabled: true
```

In retrospect, `quarkus.kubernetes-config.secrets.enabled` wasn't the best choice for this config property, sorry about that :-(